# How to perform Time series forecasting in short Interval of time data (only 8 years are given) for multiple locations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science, forecasting

I want to find the **production of field** forecasting in year 2018 and 2019 at multiple location for a short interval of data?

At each Harvesting Site(donated by index in the image and by its Latitute and Longitude) , Production of the field  can be forecasted using historical data.

[Look at the sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlArn.png)

1. How can I find the forecasting for short interval of time and for all these locations?
2. Should I train a single model for all locations or different location for different models?

There are 2418 rows means differnet 2418 field location for which we have to find out the forecasting in incoming years.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data
you can use Hierarchical linear models (also known as multilevel or mixed-effects models) to train on all location simultaneously get good results
sometime training different models would help sometimes

if you have data exactly looking simple models like LR with properly engineered features would work